# .htaccess: redirect http to https or https to http depending on URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, flags

**The solution below covers required rules:**

1) `http://www.mydomain.com , http://www.mydomain.com/?p=home , http://www.mydomain.com/?p=home1 , http://www.mydomain.com/?qqq=home` are always http, even if https are typed instead of http;

2) all the rest pages are always https, even if http was typed instead of https;

**but in practice does NOT cover**

3) `//www.mydomain.com/administration/any_file_in_admin_folder.php` should always be https as well (even with parameter ?p=home etc).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#determine if page is supposed to be http
#if it has p=home or p=home1 or qqq=home in querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=home1?|qqq=home)(&|$) [NC,OR]
#or if query string is empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
#set env var to 1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]


#all pages that are supposed to be http redirected if https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} 1
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#all other pages are sent to https if not already so
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} !1
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How to implement 3) to this code so it works? (I still have no luck and need help).
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Add the first line in 2nd & 3rd block.

i.e.  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/administration/ [NC]`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#determine if page is supposed to be http
#Requested URi must not have administration in it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/administration/ [NC]
#if it has p=home or p=home1 or qqq=home in querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=home1?|qqq=home)(&|$) [NC,OR]
#or if query string is empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
#set env var to 1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]  [L]

#all pages that are supposed to be http redirected if https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/administration/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} 1
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#all other pages are sent to https if not already so
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} !1
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works (your answer was the first I've tried). Could anybody guess, why it works, but once I create a password (I've tried both ways - using hosting panel settings ->Protect folder by password and also by creating .htaccess and .htpasswd files), the page administration/index.php redirects to 404 error page. IE says (in case if I type the wrong password):  Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. If I type it correctly, 404 error page displayed with no errors. What is that happening? No password -everythigsOK.

Comment: @Haradzieniec have you definied a separate document for `401 error`?

Comment: @Haradzieniec It works because,`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/administration/ [NC]` added in 2nd & 3rd block (which direct to `http` protocol) check that URI does not have `administration` in it.

Comment: I understand, why the updated code works (thank you very much). I've just created 401 error page. Yes, it goes to 401 error page, not to 404. I still don't understand why does it redirects to 401 error page?  Also, what happens is: if I type http://www.mydomain.com/administration/index.php (http),it asks a password first and after entering a correct password it displays 401.shtml. But,if I type https://www.mydomain.com/administration/index.php (now with httpS), it displays http://www.mydomain.com/401.shtml without asking a password(tested every time in a new browser,several times to be sure).

Comment: @Haradzieniec make sure you have set up the `.htpasswd` authentication properly.

Comment: I don't see it using Filezilla (although I see .htaccess created in /administration/). Also I don't see any new folders (as I understand, .htpasswd should be somewhere in /administration/passwordfolder). I create a password using control panel via web-browser. The same problem with redirection to an error page was several days ago, when I created .htaccess for password and .htpasswd manually and uploaded it via FileZilla. The magic is it works perfect, asks and verify the password, if I delete the .htaccess file from the root directory (the file with your code).

Comment: @Haradzieniec If you are using a shared host its very difficult to pin point the problem.

Comment: Yes, just test it one more time: removed .htaccess from the root directory. Type http://.../administration/index.php - it asks a password and loads index.php. The same with https. If I put the root .htaccess back, it redirects to 401 error page again (for http:// with asking to enter a password, for https:// - even without asking a password). What could be the reason? Can it be a problem of the server settings from the hosting provider? I asked the customer support yesterday (I beleived .htaccess had some errors and that's my fault), they said to doublecheck my .htaccess content...

Answer (score 1):

Change your first rule to:

```
#determine if page is supposed to be http
#if it has p=home or p=home1 or qqq=home in querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=home1?|qqq=home)(&|$) [NC,OR]
#or if query string is empty
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
#or if request URI is: /administration/any_file_in_admin_folder\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/*administration/any_file_in_admin_folder\.php$ [NC]
#set env var to 1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it does not work. Any file in administration folder still goes to http (from https either).

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake earlier, just fixed it. Please try.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your rule, `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` matches any URL without a querystring. Your URL, `//www.mydomain.com/administration/any_file_in_admin_folder.php` has no querystring. So `IS_HTTP` is being set to 1, and your user is being redirected to HTTP.

Try this. It's untested - but basically you're identifying the "home" querystring first, and then handling `http://www.mydomain.com` separately.

```
#if it has p=home or p=home1 or qqq=home in querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=home1?|qqq=home)(&|$) [NC]
#set env var to 1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]

RewriteRule ^$ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]
```

This might also do the trick:

```
#determine if page is supposed to be http
#if it has p=home or p=home1 or qqq=home in querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(p=home1?|qqq=home)(&|$) [NC,OR]
#or if query string is empty
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
#set env var to 1
RewriteRule ^ - [E=IS_HTTP:1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Read it carefully.